# Pass user in argument as dependence injection - symfony4

Tags: php, symfony, lexikjwtauthbundle

> Error: "Cannot resolve argument $experienceCalculator of "App\Controller\StudyActivityController::create()": Cannot autowire service "App\Service\ExperienceCalculator": argument "$user" of method "__construct()" references interface "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface" but no such service exists. Did you create a class that implements this interface?"

I'm working on an api and I need to access the user in a service that I'm passing as dependency injection in the controller. If I access the user in the controller it works fine but in the service not.

```
// src/Controller/StudyTimeController.php

public function create(
    Request $request,
    UserInterface $user,
    ExperienceCalculator $experienceCalculator
)
{
    $experienceCalculator->calculate();
}
```

It seems that autowiring isn't finding the UserInterface  when passing in the constructor of the service.

```
// src/Service/ExperienceCalculator.php

public function __construct(
    StudyTimeRepository $studyTimeRepository,
    UserInterface $user
)
{
    $this->studyTimeRepository = $studyTimeRepository;
    $this->user = $user;
}
```

So what I did was add an alias in configs so the service know which class is been passed, that worked but the user isn't populated.

```
# config/services.yaml

App\Entity\User: ~
Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface: '@App\Entity\User'
```

I don't know if thats relevant but I'm using this bundle [LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/1-configuration-reference.md) to authenticate the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autowiring entities like the user is not a good practice, since there may be
no currently logged in user or no user at all.

Instead you should use a service that is always existent to check if there is a logged in user and then receive it. For example a `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface`.

You can get the current token with the [getToken method](https://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/Storage/TokenStorageInterface.html#method_getToken) of the tokenstorage and then retrieve the current user with the [getUser method](https://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/TokenInterface.html#method_getUser) of the token like this:

```
$user = $tokenStorage->getToken() ? $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser() : null;
```

The reason you nevertheless get the user in your controller with autowiring is the user resolver added in Symfony 3.2 as [described in this blog post](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-user-value-resolver-for-controllers)